# Help needed to diagnose metalic spinning wheel sound - Chevy Sonic

Tags: chevrolet, noise

I hopelessly need your help to identify the source of the strange sound coming from my 2015 Chevy Sonic with 1.4 Turbo engine. It is like the sound of a fortune wheel hitting at metallic flapper coming from the engine or somewhere close to the engine. I start hearing this sound when I am accelerating or pushing the engine such as climbing uphill. The level of sound does not increase but its frequency increases when the engine is pushed hard. It goes away if I remove my feet from the gas pedal. The sound does not start first few minutes when the engine is cold. I attach here the recording to explain it better.

https://voca.ro/1jiccxOfJ6J0

Here is some recent history.

I recently had a shaky car with blinking engine light and a loss of power. The mechanic has changed the coil packs and this issue has been resolved. However, after getting the car, I started having this noise issue that no one has figured out yet.

I have not much idea about cars so I would appreciate any input. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Not a diagnosis, but I wonder if it has something to do with the turbo wastegate. You're saying it only happens when you're pushing your engine. This would be the point where the turbo would do most of its work, which is also where the wastegate would be most active. The wastegate helps keep the turbo boost where it needs to be and becomes active when the turbo has reached maximum allowed boost. Again, not a diagnosis, but it's the only thing I can think of which might cause a metallic click at the time you're talking about. Yes, this is a reach.

Comment: Is it synchronous to the roadway, or to engine speed?  That is what causes a "tick"... one revolution of the engine? (flywheel) 2 revolutions of the engine? (cam/valves) 5-10 revolutions of the engine? (belt drive accessory) Driving 5-7' or 1.5-2m?  (wheel, tire or brake)

Comment: Hey guys, thx for the replies. I showed it to another mechanic. I guess their best guess is turbo but they are not certain. They ask me to drive until gets worse. 
It could be the turbo wastegate but I did not get any engine light for under/over boost. This makes me a little cautious. 

I don't think it's synchronous with the engine rpm, roadway or speed. My best description is the ticking frequency increases as I accelerate harder. I noticed that sometimes ticking is there even when I stop at the red light, but it goes away if I turn off the ac fan. When driving, its there even ac is off.